# VBA Bloomberg Formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula, bloomberg

I have a problem with my code, here it is:

```
Sheets("Data - Backtest").Cells(5, linCompteur - 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=BDH(R[-3]C[1],""PX_LAST"",""ED-"" & " & .Cells(6, 5).Value & " & ""AYA""," & .Cells(7, 5).Value & ", **""per="" & " & .Cells(9, 6).Value & "** , **""fx="" & " & .Cells(8, 5).Value & "** ,""Days=W"",""Fill=P"",""cols=2"")"
```

In the Excel it gives this,

```
=BDH(R[-3]C[1];"PX_LAST";"ED-" & 5 & "AYA";; **"per=" & d**; **"fx=" & EUR**;"Days=W";"Fill=P";"cols=2")
```

I see where is the problem, it's d and EUR, it should be this:

```
=BDH(R[-3]C[1];"PX_LAST";"ED-" & 5 & "AYA";;**"per=" & "d"**;**"fx=" & "EUR"**;"Days=W";"Fill=P";"cols=2";"cols=2;rows=1305")
```

but I don't know how to do this for the equivalent in VBA.

Comment: What cell or cells do you want to put this formula into?

Comment: Given the complex nature of the formula, it might have been a good idea to show us what it was intended to look like.

Comment: Yes sorry, I juste delete the cells in the first formula beaucse it was too long but I know the error is not coming from here 100% sure, it was intended to look like the 3rd formula I gave or =BDH(R[-3]C[1];"PX_LAST";"ED-" & 5 & "AYA";; "per=d"; "fx=EUR";"Days=W";"Fill=P";"cols=2")

Comment: @hichamkortbi does this formula work in excel ?

Comment: yes, it's working, the only thing that change from the others is the way of d and EUR are writing, it's just a problem of quoted but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You can select the cell in which you've written this formula and open immediate window and write     ?Replace(selection.formular1c1, """", """""") whatever you get in there you can directly use it in VBA.

Comment: I tried but it still not working

Comment: @hichamkortbi did you put the result  inside " " in vba ?

Comment: yes of course, it gives me this: =BDH(B2,""PX_LAST"",""ED-"" & 5 & ""AYA"",, ""per="" & d, ""fx="" & EUR,""Days=W"",""Fill=P"",""cols=2"")

Comment: d and EUR are still not quoted

Comment: @hichamkortbi strange ! It gives me correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I brought some of the string concatenations together where there didn't seem any reason to separate them.

```
workSheets("Data - Backtest").Cells(5, linCompteur - 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=BDH(R[-3]C[1], ""PX_LAST"", ""ED-" & .Cells(6, 5).Value & "AYA"", " & .Cells(7, 5).Value & ", ""per=" & .Cells(9, 6).Value & """ , ""fx=" & .Cells(8, 5).Value & """ , ""Days=W"", ""Fill=P"", ""cols=2"")"
```

This is the result on the worksheet.

```
=BDH(R[-3]C[1], "PX_LAST", "ED-5AYA", , "per=d" , "fx=EUR" , "Days=W", "Fill=P", "cols=2")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works, I see now I put too much quotes